# typescript react-query mutation error TS2554: Argument of type

Tags: typescript, react-query

I'm new with typescript i use `react-query` try to us `mutate` but it cause an error

```
TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
```

iterface:

```
interface ChangePassword{
    email: string;
    password: string;
    confirmPassword: string
}
```

function:

```
 const changePasswordOnClick = useMutation<Record<string, string>, unknown, ChangePassword>(
        () => axios.post(
            url,
            { email, password, new_password}, // all fine
        ),
        {
            onSuccess: (req) => {
                console.log('Request', req)

            },

            onError: (newLogin) => {
                console.log('onError', newLogin);
            },
        },
    );
```

Problem (just piece of problem code):

```
onSubmit={async (data,
{setSubmitting, resetForm})=>{setSubmitting(true)                                 
                  changePasswordOnClick.mutate(
                     data.email, 
                    data.password, 
                    data.confirmPassword)} // TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
```

Why i'm getting this error? how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in `mutate` type we have

```js
(variables: TVariables, options?: MutateOptions) => Promise<TData>
```

and you should change `mutationFn`:

```
const changePasswordOnClick = useMutation<Record<string, string>, unknown, ChangePassword>(
  (params: ChangePassword) => axios.post(url, params),
  {
    onSuccess: (req) => {
      console.log("Request", req)
    },

    onError: (newLogin) => {
      console.log("onError", newLogin)
    },
  }
)
```

and `mutate` calling also:

```js
changePasswordOnClick.mutate({
   confirmPassword: data.confirmPassword,
   email: data.email,
   password: data.password,
})
```

To match to the type